# Application.Idle only fires after I mouse over my tray icon

Tags: c#, .net, events, notifyicon

I want to show a BalloonTip in the Application.Idle event of my program, but for some reason the Application.Idle event only fires after I mouse over the NotifyIcon. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `Application.Idle` is not getting fired? Simple way would be to log into the file whenever code enters the event and see if this happening.

Also understand that this event may not be suitable for your needs - it happens when message pump becomes empty (typically no keyboard/mouse input) - so as such you would probably receive this event too frequently (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415209/application-idle-event-significance) to understand more). In this case, I suspect that windows is suppressing the balloon tip perhaps because it is being shown too frequently.

As such, you can code to show the tip only if it has not been shown say in last 2-3 seconds. You may want to look at different implementations of Idle detection to suit your requirements - have a look at:

1. http://ellisweb.net/2008/02/detecting-application-idle-state-in-windows-forms/
2. http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/05/19/DetectingApplicationIdle.aspx
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Application_Idle.aspx

Comment: Getting blocked by windows actually makes sense, the mouseover might be stopping the idel events, which causes the form to be unblocked so it finally gets shown. Thanks!